# Car has started abnormally slowing when clutch engaged

Tags: brakes, clutch, vauxhall

A couple of days ago was turning into my street and I noticed that I was slowing down when I engaged the clutch to shift down. I would expect to coast with the clutch depressed but the car was actively slowing, it felt almost like engine braking. When I pulled up to stop it was more pronounced.

What would cause this? Car is a 2004 vauxhall Astra.

Comment: Confused here, is the clutch engaged ie up or disengaged ie down? Also had you checked the handbrake?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Sounds like the brakes are binding.